# How to get arrow key input in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, input

So i am making a console treasure finding game in c++ which takes arrow keys as inputs and increments or decrements the values of coordinates of player. I read that there is no ASCII code for these keys so how can i get the arrow keys as input? Also it would be nice if you suggest me an alternative to getch(). I am using Visual studio on 64 bit Win 7. Thanks.

Here's my code:
[Code sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URSwy.png)

Comment: DO you mind looking at my code which i have just added and suggesting a detailed alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go, 2 minutes of googling.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/210388-how-to-track-arrow-keys-in-c/page__p__1222836&#entry1222836